# Can I make console.log() print a custom message for a class?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Similar to `Date`, I'd like to customize the label printed in the console for my class.

```js
const d = new Date(123);
console.log(d);

// Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)


class MyClass {
  constructor(a, b, c) {
    this._a = a;
    this._b = b;
    this._c = c;
  }
}

const t = new MyClass(1, "2", 3);
console.log(t);

// MyClass {_a: 1, _b: "2", _c: 3}  <----- Can I customize this?
```

Is there a special function I need to implement to output a different label when calling `console.log()` ?

p.s:- watch the console of browser to see the `Label value` format output

Comment: You can create custom function that uses conditions for "typeof" and print different message according to the type

Comment: override console.log to check if the param is your type then call your format function